# Filtered Index hint rejected by SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, filtered-index

I have a filtered non-clustered index that SQL Server is not using. I'm pretty sure the optimizer is doing the right choice but I would like to force it to run with that index so I can compare the plan and see why it's more expensive.

I've removed everything from the query and I'm just selecting the column that is being filtered.

Index definition:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_all
    ON tbl_test (CommentDateTime, name)
    INCLUDE (comment, CommentByType)
    WHERE CommentByType='INT';
```

The query I'm trying to run is:

```
SELECT CommentByType
FROM tbl_test WITH (INDEX (idx_all))
WHERE CommentByType='INT';
```

And SQL Server is returning the following error:

```
Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query.
Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.
```

I've read a lot about the column filtered being included either in the key or as include column but nothing helps.

[image]

Comment: Is that the exact query (i.e. no parameters) and exact index definition?

Comment: Hi there,  yes! that's the exactly query i'm running. I had much more but i was getting that error so i removed every other part of the query so i could start from scratch but i'm getting the same error. The version is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5538.0 (X64) 
 Apr  3 2015 14:50:02 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) . the table schema is the following :

Full schema of the table and indexes can be seen here: http://tinypic.com/r/15qynbq/9 
PS: the idx_all is filtered on the column I said

Answer (score 10):

I can reproduce this in a database with `PARAMETERIZATION FORCED`.

```
CREATE DATABASE D1

ALTER DATABASE D1 SET PARAMETERIZATION FORCED

GO

USE D1

CREATE TABLE tbl_test
(
CommentDateTime DATETIME,
name VARCHAR(50),
comment VARCHAR(50),
CommentByType VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_all
    ON tbl_test (CommentDateTime, name)
    INCLUDE (comment, CommentByType)
    WHERE CommentByType='INT';

SELECT CommentByType
FROM tbl_test WITH (INDEX (idx_all))
WHERE CommentByType='INT'
--OPTION (RECOMPILE)
;
```

The literal then gets parameterised and it is no longer guaranteed that the filtered index will match

```
where CommentByType = @0
```

In which case `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` allows the hint to succeed.

Comment: I think I do have forced PARAMETERIZATION on..
Is there any explanation why the query optimizer with forced parameterization would return an error ?Many thanks

Comment: @MrKudz - Because the parameterised plan with `where CommentByType = @0` needs to work for any possible value of `@0` - not just `'INT'` so there is no guarantee that the filtered index will be suitable. i.e. `SELECT CommentByType FROM tbl_test WITH (INDEX (idx_all)) WHERE CommentByType='SOMEOTHERVALUE'` wouldn't work.